# Do pickaxes, felling axes, torches count as weapons for perks?

Tags: gnomoria

There are formation perks like  "Keep your eyes open" and Position perks such as "Way of the Gnome" that give bonuses if the gnome does or does not have a (melee) weapon equipped.

I know that shields count as weapons, but what about tools such as mentioned in the title, or improvised weapons such as a wheelbarrow or even furniture that happens to be carried?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Improvised weapons use brawling skill. I think they count as blunt weapons. Torches are weapons. Tools are also weapons, using axe or hammer skill.